# How to use a react component in express server

Tags: reactjs, express

I am trying to make a way for some to upload a file to my express backend but the form for this page is in a react component. How could I use my react component `ConverterSec2` in my `get` function?

server.js:

```
import ConverterSec2 from "./ihertz_website/src/pages/Converter/ConverterSec2"
const express = require('express')
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//console.log that your server is up and running
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Listening to port 5000'));

//create GET route
app.get('/express_backend', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + { ConverterSec2 }) //error
});
```

ConverterSec2:

```
import React, { Component } from "react"
import "../Converter/Converter.css"

class ConverterSec2 extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="sec2">
               <form method="POST" action="/" encType="multipart/form-data">
                 <input type="file" name="file"/>
                 <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
              </form>
           </div>    
       )
   }
}

export default ConverterSec2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a proxy at the end of your package.json like so:

```
{
  "name": "some name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "serve": "firebase emulators:start --only hosting,firestore"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
}
```

and then in your request within the component, use a package, such as axios and do the following:

```
axios.get('/express_backend')
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, I knew it was possible but just needed some guidance. I did not know what Axios was until now.